# VB.NET: Stop smoothly in debug.assert (false) line

Tags: vb.net, debugging, messagebox

I always write code like this:

```
If SomethingIsTrue Then
    'DoThis
ElseIf SomeOtherThingIsTrue Then
    'DoThat
Else
    Debug.Assert (False)'Doh!! I forgot to handle a certain condition
End If
```

In VB6 this worked great. During testing my app in the IDE, it just stopped in the Debug.Assert(False) line, and I saw where I missed something.

But VB.NET does not stop there but instead gives me a huge messagebox. This seems to be standard behaviour for Debug.Assert.

I have 2 questions, please:
1) How can I make it stop smoothly in that line instead of showing the messagebox?
2) How can I make it so that at runtime (!) no messagebox is shown but instead my application just keeps running without stopping or showing a messagebox?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would write something along this line:

```
if debugger.isattached=True then
   debugger.break
end if
```

Just wrap it in a shared sub, and you can simply call it in the else statement.

The code is typed without visual studio at hand, so I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it stop smoothly in that line instead of showing the messagebox?

Just click <kbd>Retry</kbd> on the message box that pops up. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z.aspx):

> Clicking Retry sends you to the code in the debugger if your application is running in a debugger, or offers to open a debugger if it is not.

Clicking <kbd>Ignore</kbd> will, well, ignore the message.

---

> How can I make it so that at runtime (!) no messagebox is shown but instead my application just keeps running without stopping or showing a messagebox?

I don't mean what you mean with *at runtime*, since all asserts happen while your code is running, hence at runtime.

If you mean that asserts should be ignored while running your application without a debugger, just make a **release build** instead of a debug build. The `Debug.Assert` method works only in debug builds, and the point of debug builds is that they are easy to debug.

---

If you want nonetheless suppress the message box, see [**Customizing Assert behavior**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcc4x86.aspx#BKMK_Customizing_Assert_behavior):

> For example, you could override the [TraceListener.Fail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.fail.aspx) method to write to an event log instead of displaying the Assertion Failed dialog box.
>
> To customize the output in this way, your program must contain a listener, and you must inherit from [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) and override its [TraceListener.Fail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.fail.aspx) method.

Comment: I like your solution, but I had the impression it is too complicated for such a simple task.
Additionally: If he ships his debug code to the customer, your solution does not help. Unfortunately, sometimes you need to ship debug code :/

Comment: @ChristianSauer Why would you ever ship a debug build to a customer?

Comment: If a problem occurs which I cannot replicate on my PC. I am working at a small company and I do not have 5 computers to test all possible combinations of soft- and hardware. os if an internal customer reports a problem, I can simply remote in and attach a debugger.

Comment: @ChristianSauer if you are debugging remotely on the client's machine, then the warning dialog wouldn't be a problem.